# What is the best software to simulate a Brownian Ratchet?

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, simulations, software, brownian-motion

I'm trying to simulate a Brownian Ratchet, but don't know the best approach to tackle the problem.

These are my inputs for the simulation that will each be varied one by one:

Number of particles in the gas surrounding the ratchet.
Size of the particles.
Size of the ratchet's pawl.
Size of the ratchet's paddle.

My output that I want to get from the simulation is:

Know when the ratchet moves forwards and backwards.

Any and all thoughts/suggestions/questions are very much appreciated :)

Also, I have a goodish enough background in computer science, specifically C++, java, and python to be able to develop this if I were to using a physics engine of sorts if there are some youtube videos or something to get me started. I don't think I could develop all of the collision mechanisms on my own.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use Johnson noise and a diode instead? It's a more practical implementation of the same type of problem.

Comment: How does Johnson noise and a diode tackle the same problem?